# gulp js and css doesn't work

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm using `gulp` to package my project,and I found the `.js` and `.css` file not appear in the `dist`,seems the filter doesn't find the file or something else.

**here is my `gulpfile.js`**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpLoadPlugins = require('gulp-load-plugins');
var plugins = gulpLoadPlugins();
var rubySass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
gulp.task('build', ['coffee','styles','fonts','images','html','transJson','venderStyle','xmlStyle'], function () {
    var htmlFilter = plugins.filter('*.html',{restore: true});
    var jsFilter = plugins.filter('**/*.js',{restore: true});
    var cssFilter = plugins.filter('**/*.css',{restore: true});
    var assets;
    return gulp.src('app/index.html')
        .pipe(assets = plugins.useref.assets())
        .pipe(plugins.rev())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer({
            browsers:  ['> 0%'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.csso())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(plugins.useref())
        .pipe(plugins.revReplace())
        .pipe(htmlFilter)
        .pipe(plugins.minifyHtml({
            empty: true,
            spare: true,
            quotes: true,
            conditionals: true
        }))
        .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
gulp.task('clean', require('del').bind(null, [ 'dist']));

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('build');
});
```

after I run `gulp` ,the `dist` folder doesn't append the `.js` or `.css` file

**It is strange that another project's `gulpfile.js` is exactly the same as this one,but it works well.**

**this is the result of my dist**

[image]

only the `.html` file appear

**this is the old project's,and the `gulpfile.js` is same as the new one**

[image]

> Problem solve ,Missing the 
>   `<!-- build:css(app) css/main.css -->` `<!-- endbuild -->`
>   in `index.html`

Comment: just an advice, never have one big task, split it in smaler ones - easier to debug

Comment: Thanks for your advice